# HMR fails with Angular 9 + IVY: Type AppComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and AppModule

Tags: angular, webpack-hmr, hot-module-replacement, angular9, angular-ivy

**Affected Package**

HMR + IVY

**Is this a regression?**

pre-IVY, it works

**Description**

Seems IVY and HMR don't play well together? However I've seen tickets of them that are closed so I suppose it should be possible.
I have on re-load after code change:

> Unnhandled Promise rejection: Type AppComponent is part of the
>   declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and AppModule! Please consider
>   moving AppComponent to a higher module that imports AppModule and
>   AppModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and
>   includes AppComponent then import that NgModule in AppModule and
>   AppModule.
>   Type Background is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule
>   and AppModule! Please consider moving Background to a higher module
>   that imports AppModule and AppModule. You can also create a new
>   NgModule that exports and includes Background then import that
>   NgModule in AppModule and AppModule.

...

We can see how others investigated better:
https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/storybookjs/storybook/8494/551763214

Current Environment

Angular Version:

**ng 9.0.1**

**cli 9.0.1**

Comment: Did you find a solution to the matter?

Comment: No yet, Dear @SimonDragsbæk :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Toggle on AOT in your angular.json config file, that should do it

Here is the structure of where:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "x": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "aot": true,
          },
          "configurations": {
            "local": {
              "aot": true
            },
```

Alternatively, just for testing purposes, you can run with the `aot` flag instead

```
ng serve --aot=true
```

### Update

As of Angular version 11 it is fully functional again

## Update

Note this is only fixing so you can actually work on your project, for now. The angular team is working on a solution so we can get our fully HMR support back, hopefully very soon.

Look here for the related issue in the angular repo
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35265

And here for the PR put out to fix it (still in draft)
https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/37474

Comment: Excellent, Dear Simon. This configuration worked for me: I understand that hmr must now be available to run in build AoT as IVY by default does.

Comment: It triggers a full page reload for me...not working right.

Comment: @TetraDev but do you still get the error message: "Type AppComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules..." - The other part is about configuring HMR correctly, try to hit up the angularclass/hmr repo for more information

Comment: @TetraDev I have looked into the issue a bit more extensively and updated this answer accordingly.

Comment: @SimonDragsbæk I didn't get any other errors. Just full module dependency tree gets reloaded on each HMR update. Awful to deal with this for nearly all of 2020!

Comment: @TetraDev which is awful and I think this answer should serve as a "status page" for the issue In question

Comment: @SimonDragsbæk I agree. Come on team Angular, you can do it!

Comment: @TetraDev It got fixed by ng11 but you might already know this